# Tar and Rsync in a single go using pipe

Tags: linux, pipe, tar, rsync

I want to create a zipped file with tar command and rsync the output file to remote machine.
I have tried the following:

```
tar -cjvf etc.tar.bz /etc | rsync -r &1 user@remoteip:/home/user/

tar -cjvf etc.tar.bz /etc | rsync -r '{}' user@remoteip:/home/user/

tar -cjvf etc.tar.bz /etc | rsync -r '{}' 'user@remoteip:/home/user/'
```

None of them work. Please tell me how to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest to use tar and ssh.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2):

You are piping the result of tar to rsync. It will not work.
You can try:

```
tar -cjvf etc.tar.bz /etc ; rsync etc.tar.bz user@remoteip:/home/user/
```

Or If you send directly the file through the network:

```
tar cjvf - /etc | ssh user@remoteip "cat > /home/user/etc.tar.bz"
```

Comment: I would argue that the use of rsync is redundant as it is for incremental copying of directory trees, none of which is needed here.  Therefore the second example given is the best one.

Comment: @trent If they're trying to overwrite an older version of `etc.tar.bz`, then rsync will be much more efficient if the churn between the versions isn't large.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command to pipe directly to tar on the other side

`tar cjvf - /etc | ssh user@hostname "tar xvjf - --keep-newer-files"`